# Does the compiler optimize a functor field initialized in its declaration by a lambda to make the lambda static?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

If I write a class like I have below:

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass1
    {
        //example Functor
        public Func<int, bool> IsLeapYear { get; set; } = (year) => (year % 4u == 0u && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }
}
```

Do I have a different instance of the functor for every instance of MyClass or a reference for the same one?

What if I do this?

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass2
    {
        private static readonly Func<int, bool> _isLeapYear = (year) => (year % 4u == 0u && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
        public Func<int, bool> IsLeapYear { get; set; } = _isLeapYear;
    }
}
```

I would expect every instance of MyClass2 to hold the same instance of the functor for sure in this case. **I want to know if the code of MyClass1 is equivalent to that of MyClass2** because I have a ton of functors in the same class, and I was hoping to make my code shorter.

I use .NetCore 3.1, C# 8.0, Visual Studio Enterprise 2019. (I tagged the question with [.net-core-3.1](/questions/tagged/.net-core-3.1) because I figured the compiler is part of the framework).

[Edit: highlighted in bold the actual question]

Comment: You asked a lot of questions at once - can you either number them, or pick the most important part of the question to answer?  Also, why make these lambda expressions in the first place?  Seems the calculation of IsLeapYear isn't really something that should be replaced with another function, right?  Can't it just be a static method somewhere?  Or are we missing something?

Comment: That was just an silly example. In my actual scenario the class represents sort of a configuration object, with many properties, a lot of them are functors, all of them with a default implementation that corresponds to the default configuration. Thank you for the tip on highlighting the important part of the question. I have done so.

Comment: No worries, just looking for clarity.  Glad @weichch sorted out what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be the same instance.

```
public class MyClass1
{
    //example Functor
    public Func<int, bool> IsLeapYear { get; set; } = 
        (year) => (year % 4u == 0u && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

var a = new MyClass1();
var b = new MyClass1();

// result = true
var result = object.ReferenceEquals(a.IsLeapYear, b.IsLeapYear);
```